# Heroku: Git error after application fork

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, push

**Setup:**

I have a Node.js (MEAN fullstack) application (ie. myApp) deployed on heroku that **works fine**. I deploy with standard git push

```
$ git push heroku master
```

I wanted to create a staging replica of the application and used heroku fork to do so (as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app) .

```
$ heroku fork -a myApp myApp-staging
```

The **staging application also works fine** with its' own database and has its' own set of config variables (es expected). !!! IMPORTANT

I also created a new git remote

```
$ git remote add staging git@heroku.com:myApp-staging.git
// repo address taken from "heroku info -a myApp-staging"
```

**Problem:**

1) If I try to push to production ie. "git push heroku master" it
    works fine.

2) If I try to push to staging

```
$ git push staging master
```

I get "Permission denied (publickey)."
3) If I try to clone my staging application git repo to another directory I get an empty repo

```
$ heroku git:clone -a industryhub-staging
// warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository
```

Where is my staging repo? Which code is Heroku running on my staging instance? An finally - how do I push to staging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Here for posterity.

The error was the **wrong remote** for the staging app. I created it with

```
$ git remote add staging git@heroku.com:myApp-staging.git
```

and I had

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myApp.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myApp.git (push)
staging git@heroku.com:myApp-staging.git (fetch) // wrong
staging git@heroku.com:myApp-staging.git (push)  // wrong
```

I should have done

```
$ git remote add staging https://git.heroku.com/myApp-staging.git // over https
```

Now my git shows

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myApp.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myApp.git (push)
staging https://git.heroku.com/myApp-staging.git (fetch) // OK
staging https://git.heroku.com/myApp-staging.git (push)  // OK
```

And the life is peachy again!

---

Note: Heroku says that the **new repo IS EMPTY after forking an app**. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app#forked-app-state